# Message doesn't print without \n and prints with \n

Tags: c++, linux, file

I've written the following code:

```
#include <sys/timerfd.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Test_message");
    int tfd;
    uint64_t count;
    tfd= timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,0);
    itimerspec itimer;
    itimer.it_interval={1,0};
    itimer.it_value={1,0};
    timerfd_settime(tfd,0,&itimer,NULL);
    while(true)
    {
        read(tfd, &count, sizeof(count));
    }
}
```

When I'm compiling and linking we have no output to console. But I'm expected that the `Test_message` will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run the program.
2. Do not forget buffering - "Test message" will be their until it is flushed. See `fflush`